# Column 'updated_at' in order clause is ambiguous -laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

```
 $sortBy = !empty($request->sort_by)? $request->sort_by :'updated_at';
 if (!empty($searchtext)) {
 $query->join('customers', 'reviews.id', '=', 'customers.id');
 $query->where("reviews.text", "like", "%$searchtext%")
 $query->select('customers*','reviews.text');  
 }                                                     
 $querylist = $query->orderBy($sortBy, $sortOrder)->paginate($pageSize);
 return $querylist;
```

for this line I am getting error as

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in order
> clause is ambiguous

I tried using -

```
$sortBy = !empty($request->sort_by)? $request->sort_by :'customers.updated_at';
```

but then the application is not working its says loading fail.

Comment: you also need to paste your query here else we cannot assume what is the issue

Comment: I think we still can't see the whole query - please can you share it?  Most likely there are a couple of tables that have an 'updated_at' column, and so the SQL server doesn't know which one to use, but it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the query.

Comment: @RobEyre both the tables (customers and review) is having updated_at column

Comment: So you'll need to specifiy which 'updated_at' column you want to sort by then.  You said 'the application is not working' - please share more details?

Comment: @RobEyre `$sortBy = !empty($request->sort_by)? $request->sort_by :'customers.updated_at';`   i tried this but didnt worked

Comment: Same error, or a different one?

Comment: loading failed ... application didnt work after that , so i revert the chnages @RobEyre

Comment: OK so it looks like you have two errors - one with the SQL sort by (which you have now fixed), and another somewhere else in your code